# Volley Request from another class not activity

Tags: java, android

I am making a volley String request from a separate class and return the result to main activity

```
    public class FetchFlages {
    Context context;
    String
    placeurl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json
    query=";
    String myapi = "&key=AIzaSyBuI5wpF733jBS8s7HzjybE1rYAp1hA5tA";
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String abc=null;


public FetchFlages(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
}
public String getPhotoReference(){

    String url = placeurl +"China"+myapi;
   StringRequest objectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
           new Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                   abc = response;
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volly Error",error.toString());
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
    return abc;
    }
    }
```

and in  main Class

```
    FetchFlages fetchFlages = new FetchFlages(this);
    flag = fetchFlages.getPhotoReference();
    String g = flag;
```

But i can't get any value from that...the value of abc always return null
and
When i run debugger then debugger not comes neither on Volley on Response Listener method and nor on Error Listener Method...Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

This is because as soon as getPhotoReference() is called, its returning the value. The network call is still running. Create a listener and call the listener method on onRespose

Sample pseudo code:

CustomListener.java

```
public interface CustomListener{
    void onVolleyResponse(String response);
}
```

FetchFlages.java

```
public class FetchFlages {
    Context context;
    String placeurl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/jsonquery=";
    String myapi = "&key=AIzaSyBuI5wpF733jBS8s7HzjybE1rYAp1hA5tA";
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    CustomListener listener = null; //Your listener instance


public FetchFlages(Context context, CustomListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
}
public void getPhotoReference(){

    String url = placeurl +"China"+myapi;
    StringRequest objectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
       new Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
               listener.onVolleyResponse(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("Volly Error",error.toString());
    }
});
requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
}
}
```

Now in your main activity,

```
FetchFlages fetchFlages = new FetchFlages(this, new CustomListener() {
    @Override
    public void onVolleyResponse(String response) {
        //response is your response
    }
});

fetchFlages.getPhotoReference()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use interface Method like:

```
public class FetchFlages {
Context context;
String placeurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=";
String myapi = "&key=AIzaSyBuI5wpF733jBS8s7HzjybE1rYAp1hA5tA";
RequestQueue requestQueue;

IResult result;


public FetchFlages(Context context, IResult result) {
    this.context = context;
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    this.result = result;
}

public void getPhotoReference() {

    String url = placeurl + "China" + myapi;
    StringRequest objectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    result.notifySuccess(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volly Error", error.toString());
            result.notifyError(error);
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(objectRequest);

}

public interface IResult {
    public void notifySuccess(String response);

    public void notifyError(VolleyError error);
}
```

and call it:

```
FetchFlages fetchFlages = new FetchFlages(this, new IResult() {
    @Override
    public void notifySuccess(String response) {
        //response here
        Log.e("responce",response);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyError(VolleyError error) {
        //error here
    }
});
fetchFlages.getPhotoReference()
```

Comment: use as it is it will help you

Comment: But when i add the response to a list..and i when i print the list after             
`fetchFlages.getPhotosRefernce   Log.d("Mylist",myList.toString)`    My List print always empty

Comment: your url have ? missing i have updated it copy my code and use it it will work for u

Comment: response comes in Log.e("responce",response); use as your requirement

Comment: I already corrected the url ...i mean data come and adds in list...like   `FetchFlages fetchFlages = new FetchFlages(this, new IResult() {
    @Override
    public void notifySuccess(String response) {
        //response here
        Log.e("responce",response);    //Responce is added to list myList.add(responce);    
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyError(VolleyError error) {
//error here
    }
});
fetchFlages.getPhotoReference()    Log.d("My List",myList.toString)`

Comment: If i show list through log within onNotifySuceess it has all the things    But when i run log after  `fetchFlags.getPhotoRefernce` the List is empty..why?

Comment: fetchFlags.getPhotoRefernce() is a request calling method your responce is only in response variable